# Cannot ping Rapsberry from another Raspberry

Tags: ping, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have two raspberry pi zeros. Both connected to my WIFI.

1. I can ssh them from my laptop.
2. They can ping my laptop & my router.
3. My laptop can ping them.

when I try to ping one raspberry from the other one it does not reply.

RPI-Zero:

```
uname -a 
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32+ #1538 Thu Mar 31 19:37:58 BST 2022 armv6l GNU/Linux

cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface wlan0
       static ip_address=192.168.1.123
       static routers=192.168.1.1
```

RPI-Zero2:

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v7+ #1538 SMP Thu Mar 31 19:38:48 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux


cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.1.131/24
    static routers=192.168.1.1
```

**When you ping the other one from raspberry:**

[image]

[image]

**But when you ping them from laptop**

[image]

Comment: how is the laptop connected to the network?

Comment: the laptop is connected using LAN cable to my ADSL router.

Comment: ok, that means that you have more troubleshooting tests to run

Comment: can you guide me ?

Comment: @jsotola you gave me the idea... it is related to WIFI.

Comment: that's what I was thinking

Comment: Have you disabled "Wifi Protection" on your router?

Comment: yes I have disabled "Wifi AP Isolation" on the router. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error was because ADSL Router has AP Isolation enabled. That is it.
AP Isolation prevents units connected over the wifi from accessing each other although they connect to the same wifi. It is a security feature in routers but it must be disabled in my scenario.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).